# Are there alternative nonsymmetric symbols to signify nonsymmetrical operations like $-$, $|$ etc...

Tags: notation, binary-operations

Commonly it's just assumed that $5-4$ means $5+(-4)$ and $7\div2 = 7\times\frac{1}{2}$, but $-$ is symmetric so I was wondering if there are there some nonsymmetric symbols like $5\rightharpoondown4 = 5+(-4)$ while $5\leftharpoondown4 = (-5)+4$ which would signify the direction of the operation ? Like division is sometimes written $5/4 = 5\times\frac{1}{4}$ and $5\setminus4 = \frac{1}{5}\times 4$.

I know it may not be standard notation, but I was wondering if someone have made use of it?

Comment: I've never seen this one: $5\setminus4 = \frac{1}{5}\times 4$.

Comment: @GitGud Probably not too common, but it was mentioned on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Notation) as being in use on some mathematical software on computers. In which case $a/b = b\setminus a$.

Comment: I've been thinking about a similar thing with regards the way students learn. On the one hand we say $n \times 2$ should be written $2n$ but can't write $n \div 2$ as $2/n$.

Comment: @Karl One way to explain that is that multiplication over the integers are commutative, and $n\times2 = 2\times x = 2x$, where the $2x$ is just a shorthand way of writing $2\times x$. Maybe $2\times x$ should be used instead of $2x$ when learning this? When $a\times b = b\times a,\quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ it makes sense to use a symmetric symbol, but this is not always true like $a\times b \neq b\times a,\quad a,b \in \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: I started thinking about it whilst teaching multiplication and division to struggling students. Demonstrating the comutativity of multiplication in a rectangular array of dots seemed to adversely effect their understanding of division

Comment: I've sometimes seen ${^-}4 + 5$, for example in older typewritten texts. It's not quite what you were looking for, but it does have the advantage of being obviously not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

The exact same problem is reported in 1929 famous Cajori book "History of mathematical notation" pag 275 in my edition.
"  The sign : is a survival of old mathematical notation; it is short and neat, but it has the fault of being symmetrical toward the right and toward the left, that is , of being a symmetrical sign of an asymmetrical operation."
On the same book the use of y/x and $y \overline{x} $ are reported.

Answer (score 1):

"If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

The apparent symmetry of signs does not mean the commutativity of operations.

As long as we know to read from left to right, we are safe.

We are used to these symbols and creating new signs bring more problems.

We know what $5-4$ means and we also know that $5-4$ is not the same as $4-5$. Similarly we know that $20/4$ is not the same as$4/20$